# Setting multiple button Images from UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

In my view i have three 4 buttons. When you click on a button it pops up the UIPickerView so you can choose an image from the Library to use as a Profile image. However, when didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is called, it keeps storing the different photos for the same button.
Click button 1, choose image, sets image from Button 1
Click button 2, choose image, sets image for Button 1 again, and not for button two.
Same thing with all 4 buttons. keeps setting image for first button.

```
func promptForCamera() {

    let controller = UIImagePickerController()
    controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    controller.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func promptForPhotoRoll() {

    let controller = UIImagePickerController()

    controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    controller.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func promptForSource() {
    let actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Image Source", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "Camera", "Photo Roll")
    actionSheet.showInView(view)

}

func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    if buttonIndex != actionSheet.firstOtherButtonIndex{
        if buttonIndex != actionSheet.firstOtherButtonIndex{
            promptForCamera()
        }
        else{
           promptForPhotoRoll()
        }
    }
}

 func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController!) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage

    self.p1Image = image


    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true , completion: nil)

    p1ImageButton.setImage(self.p1Image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)


}



@IBAction func p1PhotoTapped(sender: AnyObject) {


    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){

        promptForSource()


    }
    else{

        promptForPhotoRoll()


    }

}
```

Obviously, I know that in this didFinishPickingMedia function I am setting the Image for p1ImageButton. But how do i change this function so that it sets the image for the correlating button that was picked? Do I need 4 different didFinishPickingWithMedia functions(is that even possible)? Each time a button is picked it calls the didFinish method. Do I need to pass in some sort of parameter? Hope this all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

save your 4 ImagePickerControllers in variables and make the determination in your imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) method.

```
if (picker == pickerBla)
{

}
else if (picker == ...)
{

}
```

Comment: mate thanks for you suggestion. See my edited initial post. I posted the entire process of clicking an image, checking for camera, selecting whether I want to take a photo or choose one from library. If I use this system, Im not seeing How i can define my 4 different pickerControllers with this process. Am I missing something?